# TypeScript - how to write a declaration file for a third party package with a single global function?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a declaration file for a third party package ([latex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/latex)).
The package exports a single global function `latex()`. I tried to use the following declaration file (`src/@types/latex/index.d.ts`):

```
declare module 'latex' {
    import { Stream } from "stream";
    export function latex(latex: string | string[] | Buffer | Stream): Stream
}
```

Now I'm trying to import latex like this `import * as latex from 'latex'` but the compiler force me to invoke `latex.latex()` instead of just `latex()`.

How can I fix this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export default function latex()
```

This is ES6 modules syntax. But the original code of the latex module is using commonjs module syntax. The declaration file should therefore be

```
export = function latex()
```

Importing should be also done using commonjs way in TypeScript

```
import latex = require('latex')
```

Answer (score 1):

If the function is the default export, you can add the default keyword in your definition file:

```
export default function latex(...
```

And then you can import it and use it like this:

```
import latex from 'latex';

latex(args);
```

Comment: The compilation now works but the generated code looks like this:
`const latex_1 = require("latex");` and then `latex_1.latex(...`